# cTraversing a matrix right diagnoly

Tags: java, matrix, indexing, traversal

Given the following matrix:

```
        1  2  3
        4  5  6
        7  8  9
```

I would have to be traversed in the following order:

```
        [3],[2,6],[1,5,9],[4,8],[7]
```

I have written the code for traversing in the order of

```
        [1],[2,4],[3,5,7],[6,8],[9]
```

It works well:

```
int rows = output.length;
int cols = output[0].length;
int maxSum = rows + cols - 2;       
for (int sum = 0; sum <= maxSum; sum++) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      if (i + j - sum == 0) {
        System.out.print(output[i][j] + "\t");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i modify this code to achieve the order that I need? How can i achieve the right diagonally traversing a matrix?

Comment: what is the maxSum in ur code???

Comment: @whiletrue i have updated the code..so u can check now

Comment: Keep in mind that your solution runs in O(n^3) time. Your are traversing a data structure that is n^2 in size, so there is no reason it should take n^3 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hows about this in your inner loop ?

```
System.out.print(output[i][output[0].length-j-1] + "\t");
```

Comment: Yeah it worked. :) such a simple thing i missed..i was applying the same thing on loop iteration but somehow codnt c that i can just write it like this.thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that your solution runs in O(n^3) time. Your are traversing a data structure that is n^2 in size, so there is no reason it should take n^3 time.

Think of a matrix like this:

```
          Cols
      -2 -1  0  1  2
Rows  --------------
   0 | .  .  1  2  3
   1 | .  .  4  5  6
   2 | .  .  7  8  9
```

Then you can traverse it by selecting a starting point at row = 0 column = { 2, 1, 0, -1, -2}. For each starting point you need to print N (size of square matrix) elements at { row + 0; col + 0 }, { row + 1; col + 1 } ... { row + N - 1; col + N - 1 }. The trick is to make sure that the coordinates that you computed lie within matrix, i.e. row and col are in [0, N - 1]:

```
public class MatrixTraversal {
  public static void traverse(int[][] matrix) {
    int N = matrix.length;

    for (int startCol = N - 1; startCol > -N; startCol--) {
      int row = 0, col = startCol;
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (row + i < N && col + i < N && row + i >= 0 && col + i >= 0) {
          System.out.print(matrix[row + i][col + i] + " ");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    traverse(new int[][] {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 }
    });
  }
}
```

This solution has O(n^2) complexity and approximately N times faster than yours.